# Dapper Rainbow - How to specify table name in another schema

Tags: dapper, dapper-rainbow

I am pretty new to Dapper Rainbow so I may be missing something obvious.  Is it possible to specify the table name and if so how?

I have tried the following with no luck.

```
public class DashboardContext : Database<DashboardContext>
{
    public DashboardContext()
    {
       this.DashboardResults = new Table<DashboardResult>(this, "Monitor.DashboardResult");
    }

    public Table<DashboardResult> DashboardResults { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but it seems an error in the code. I´ve just commented the lines where is setting the constructor for tables (Database.cs) and it works.

```
    internal void InitDatabase(DbConnection connection, int commandTimeout)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
        //this.commandTimeout = commandTimeout;
        //if (tableConstructor == null)
        //{
        //    tableConstructor = CreateTableConstructorForTable();
        //}

        //tableConstructor(this as TDatabase);
    }
```

I guess this is not the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

You need to hack the rainbow source to get it to work.
Find the `CreateTableConstructor` method in the file of DataBase.cs.
Just add some code as following:

```
...
var setters = GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetValue(this, null) == null 
             && p.PropertyType.IsGenericType 
             && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == tableType)
    .Select...
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumpeling over this post like I did this is now fixed in Dapper.Rainbow version 0.1.3.

It is still in beta at this time (0.1.3-beta1) so if you want to use schema you can clone/fork the repository and run the build script. The binary output can then be used directly or packaged.

As for the table setup you need to define the table name with the name of the schema for for that particular table so for example looking at this example without schema

```
    public class MyDatabase : Database<MyDatabase>
    {
        public Table<Order> Order{ get; set; }
        public Table<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
        public Table<Item> Item { get; set; }
    }
```

Which works if you are only using dbo. but if you are for instance using say Product schema for Item you would have to define it using a constructor

```
    public class MyDatabase : Database<MyDatabase>
    {
        public Table<Order> Order{ get; set; }
        public Table<Customer> Customer{ get; set; }
        public Table<Item> Item;

        public MyDatabase()
        {
            Item = new Table<Item>(this, "Product.Item");
        }
    }
```

The rest should be as before

```
     using (var connection = DbConnections.Create())
     {
            connection.Open();
            var db = MyDatabase.Init((DbConnection)connection, commandTimeout: 2);
            var insert = db.Customer.Insert(
            // .
            //..... your object
            // .
            );
            var insertId = insert.Value;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Acorax answer, it wasn't enough for me, I needed to add brackets to the schema and table name to solve this.

So this solved me the schema problem:

```
public class MyDatabase : Database<MyDatabase>
{
    public Table<Item> Items;

    public HamenasDbSchema()
    {
        Items = new Table<User>(this, "[Schema].[Items]");
    }
}
```